# How to display several kendo charts side by side without overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have several kendo charts like this.

[image]

I want to display these charts without overlapping series.

margin, padding is not working.

**html**

```
 <table style="width:100%;table-layout:auto;">
        <tr>                
            <td id="divPrintBillFinalReportPieChart_801" style="width:20%;float:right;display:inline-block;"></td>
            <td id="divPrintBillFinalReportPieChart_802" style="width:20%;float:right;display:inline-block;"></td>
            <td id="divPrintBillFinalReportPieChart_811"style="width:20%;float:right;display:inline-block;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#divPrintBillFinalReportPieChart_801').kendoChart({
        dataSource: { data: BILAT_No_801 },
        series: [
            { type: "pie", field: "Percentage", categoryField: "DVST_Name" }
        ],
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: { visible: true, background: "transparent", template: "#= category #: \n #= value#%" }
        },
        title: { text: "부분별 임금비" },
        legend: { visible: false },
        seriesColors: ["#9de219", "#90cc38", "#068c35", "#006634", "004d38", "#033939", "#fad84a", "#ff9800", "#03a9f4", "#4caf50"],
        tooltip: { visible: true, template: "${ category } - ${ value }%" },
        chartArea: { width: 200, height: 300 }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `float:left` on each one, then use padding and margin. (This is on the html and css side of things) You could also set the width and height of the table cells to possible auto, or play around with their size until the kendo charts fit correctly.

Comment: It appears that you can set the height to 300px and width to 200px as your chart area is set to in your js.

Comment: I couldn't catch this you mentioned, Thank u ( :